# How do I find out the enum used in an EnumMap?

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I have a test class with an internal enum and an EnumMap like the following. How do I find out which enum is used within the EnumMap?

```
enum MyEnum { ENUM1, ENUM2 }
EnumMap<MyEnum, String> emap = new EnumMap<>( MyEnum.class );
public void discover() {
  Class<?> eclass = ???;
  System.out.println( eclass );
}
```

should print

> MyEnum.class

Comment: I have rolled back your edit. The accepted answer should not be edited into your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the map is not empty, you can retrieve one key and check its class. Otherwise the only way is to access the `keyType` private field of the EnumMap via reflection (the field is not exposed through the public API).

In the first case you can do:

```
Iterator<?> it = map.keySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  Object key = it.next();
  if (key != null) return key.getDeclaringClass();
}
```

In the second case (which obviously also works for non empty enums) you can use:

```
private static Class<?> enumMapType(EnumMap<?, ?> map) {
  try {
    Field keyType = EnumMap.class.getDeclaredField("keyType");
    keyType.setAccessible(true);
    return (Class<?>) keyType.get(map);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
    throw new AssertionError("Could not find EnumMap type", e);
  }
}
```

This could break if the internal implementation of `EnumMap` changes and it would be better to find a way around your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I do not like to rely on a private field here I use this solution. I have modified my code in the question itself.

Comment: It should be `getDeclaringClass` not `getClass`. You need to change the signature of the method to make the method `getDeclaringClass` visible.

Answer (score 1):

If the `EnumMap` is not empty you can use

```
map.keySet().iterator().next().getDeclaringClass();
```

`getClass()` does not work if the enum has a method with a constant-specific implementation.

If the `EnumMap` is empty you could use reflection, as shown in @assylias's answer.

An alternative is to subclass `EnumMap` and write a `public` getter.

```
public final class MyEnumMap<K extends Enum<K>, V> extends EnumMap<K, V> {

    private final Class<K> keyType;

    public MyEnumMap(Class<K> keyType) {
        super(keyType);
        this.keyType = keyType;
    }

    public Class<K> keyType() { return keyType; }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice approach: subclassing EnumMap and provide a getter for that field.

Answer (score 1):

In case you cannot subclass the `EnumMap`, serializing into an `ObjectOutputStream` and de-serializing with a specialized `ObjectInputStream` which resolves the `EnumMap` class descriptor to your own subclass of `EnumMap` can help. Your subclass must have the same `serialVersionUID` as `java.util.EnumMap` and must have simple name `EnumMap`, not be an inner class, but can live in any package.

Here is an example for such an `EnumMap` subclass:

```
package your.package.name.here;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

/**
 * A serialization-compatible mock for {@link java.util.EnumMap} that uses an equal {@link #serialVersionUID} and a
 * compatible set of fields. When de-serializing an {@link java.util.EnumMap} instance into an instance of this class,
 * e.g., by overriding {@link ObjectInputStream}'s {@link ObjectInputStream#resolveClass} method such that it delivers
 * this class instead of {@link java.util.EnumMap}, the fields are made accessible through getters; in particular,
 * {@link #getKeyType()} reveals the original {@link java.util.EnumMap}'s key type, even if the map is empty.<p>
 * 
 * The {@link EnumMap#getEnumMapKeyType(java.util.EnumMap)} method can be used to determine the key type of any
 * {@link java.util.EnumMap}, even if it's empty.
 */
class EnumMap<K extends Enum<K>, V> extends java.util.EnumMap<K, V> {
    private final Class<K> keyType;
    private transient K[] keyUniverse;
    private transient Object[] vals;
    private transient int size = 0;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 458661240069192865L;
    
    EnumMap(Class<K> c) {
        super(c);
        keyType = null;
    }
    
    public K[] getKeyUniverse() {
        return keyUniverse;
    }

    public Object[] getVals() {
        return vals;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public Class<K> getKeyType() {
        return keyType;
    }

    /**
     * Reconstitute the <tt>EnumMap</tt> instance from a stream (i.e., deserialize it).
     */
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s) throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // Read in the key type and any hidden stuff
        s.defaultReadObject();
        // Read in size (number of Mappings)
        int size = s.readInt();
        // Read the keys and values, and put the mappings in the HashMap
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            s.readObject(); // key
            s.readObject(); // value
        }
    }
}
```

Note the public getters for the fields. With this, you can implement a little utility that provides the specialized ObjectInputStream and then fetches the key type from the instance of your specialized EnumMap, like this:

```
package your.package.name.here;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectStreamClass;

public class EnumMapUtil {
    private static class MyObjectInputStream extends ObjectInputStream {
        public MyObjectInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
            super(in);
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?> resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass desc) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            final Class<?> result;
            if (desc.getName().equals("java.util.EnumMap")) {
                result = your.package.name.here.EnumMap.class;
            } else {
                result = super.resolveClass(desc);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    
    public static <K extends Enum<K>, V> Class<K> getKeyType(java.util.EnumMap<K, V> enumMap) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        final Class<K> result;
        if (enumMap.isEmpty()) {
            final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            oos.writeObject(enumMap);
            oos.close();
            final ObjectInputStream ois = new MyObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final your.package.name.here.EnumMap<K, V> readMap = (your.package.name.here.EnumMap<K, V>) ois.readObject();
            final Class<K> keyType = readMap.getKeyType();
            result = keyType;
        } else {
            result = enumMap.keySet().iterator().next().getDeclaringClass();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

You should then be able to use something like `EnumMapUtil.getKeyType(myEmptyEnumMap)` which returns the enum's `Class` object on which you could then, e.g., call `getEnumConstants()`.

Comment: What a stupid hack. +1