# How do I create a generic JPA converter for an EnumMap?

Tags: java, generics, jpa, reflection, converters

I want to create a generic JPA converter to convert an EnumMap into a string and vice versa. At moment I have the following code:

```
@Converter
public class EnumMapConverter4jpa implements AttributeConverter<EnumMap<?, Object> value ) {
  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn( EnumMap<?, Object> value ) {
    if ( value == null ) return null;
    String text = "";
    for ( Entry<?, Object> entry : value.entrySet()) {
      text += " " + entry.getKey.toString() + ":" + entry.getValue().toString();
    }
    return ( text.length() > 0 ? text.substring( 2 ) : null );
  }

@Override
public EnumMap<?, Object> convertToEntityAttribute( String value ) {
  if ( value == null ) return null;
  EnumMap<?, Object> emap = null; // TODO instantiate new map here
  String[] elements = value.split( " " );
  for ( String element : elements ) {
    String[] keyval = element.split( ":" );
    System.out.println( keyval[0] + "=" + keyval[1] );
    // TODO: emap.put( key, value );
  }
  return emap;
}
```

Method convertToDatabaseColumn() works as expected but convertToEntityAttribute() of course is not. The underlying question here is how do I find out which enum is used in the field for which this converter is used?

Please see also [How do I find out the enum used in an EnumMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33694654/1230816)

Comment: You have to save the Enum type in the convertToDatabaseColumn also ... you cant just save the "name". Then in convertToEntityAttribute you can use it via Enum.valueOf

Comment: Interesting approach. But how do I get another parameter into method "convertToDatabaseColumn"? As far as I know there is no possibility within the JPA spec to even add another method to the converter.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a solution since such a converter is instantiated only once for all fields which use this converter.

Comment: Clearly it is a solution since you get the Enum type when convertToDatabaseColumn is called, you then store the Enum type IN THE FIELD VALUE (in the db), and then on retrieval use it again. It is not stored in the Converter instance

Comment: You really propose to store a class name in the value of a database column? That would mean to store the same name in millions of rows. This is not only bad architecture but also has memory and performance impact. I'm sorry, but I cannot accept such a solution.

Comment: That's why Neil added it as comment and not as answer ;-)